# Slight change to command to compile C++ program causes error

Tags: linux, command-line, compiling, c++

This morning , I was trying to compile a C++ program using the following command on the command line

```
g++ -o foo.cpp foo
```

I spend about an hour trying t to resolve why I kept getting undefined reference & multiple definition error till I realised that my command to compile was wrong and **it should be**

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo
```

I am just wondering what is the difference in process between `g++ -o foo.cpp foo` and `g++ foo.cpp -o foo` .

Why does placing the `-o` infront cause compilation error

Answer (score 3):

Because -o specifies the outfile. The first means that the outfile would be 'foo.cpp' whereas the second means that your outfile will be 'foo'.

The syntax of g++ is:

`gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard] [-g] [-pg] [-Olevel] [-Wwarn...] [-pedantic] [-Idir...] [-Ldir...] [-Dmacro[=defn]...] [-Umacro] [-foption...] [-mmachine-option...] [-o outfile] [@file] infile...`

Relevant man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++

Answer (score 1):

The switch `-o` takes an argument. In your case you were telling `g++` to output the resulting compilation to the file `foo.cpp`. That's not what you want.

```
$ g++ -o foo.cpp foo
```

You want to output the resulting compilation of the source file (`foo.cpp`) to the binary file `foo`.

```
$ g++ foo.cpp -o foo
```

*excerpt from g++ man page*

```
-o <file>                Place the output into <file>
```